# Customizing Website (User interface) of CKAN Data Portal

Tags: javascript, ckan, opendata

I was able to setup CKAN (Open Data Portal) similar to https://demo.ckan.org/. Now i want to customized how the portal looks. If you go through https://ckan.org/showcase you can see a lot of CKAN based data portal with excellent user interface / website design.

How can I customize how portal looks, is there any extension to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify or extend the CKAN functionality by creating your own CKAN extension. Check out the [official docs for writing extensions](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/extensions/tutorial.html#creating-a-new-extension). To modify the default design you can extend the CKANs Jinja templates by following these [docs](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/theming/templates.html)